# How does the character-like list map work in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, matrix, pygame

How does the list map work? I've seen that they look like this

```
level = [
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
    "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                     PPPPPP               P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]
```

I've seen such represented by multi-dimensional arrays as well.. and I know we iterate over them but how exactly do we make them appear them into our game at all and how are they actually called in the game development community??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "list map" as you've called it, is just a 2D map where each symbol/letter represents a different tile-texture on screen.  Each row in the map defines an on-screen row.

The code below takes the array/list from the question and draws it to the screen as either a brick-tile or a grass-tile.  Textures are from https://opengameart.org.  Basically when the `drawMap()` function is called, a double-loop iterates over the level-strings, painting a grid of 32x32 graphic bitmaps, which change for each letter.

[image: grass_32.png]    [image: brick_32.png]

The rest of the code is simply to handle the basic opening of the window,  arrow-key input and re-sizing of the window.

```
import pygame
import time
import sys

# Window size
WINDOW_WIDTH=400
WINDOW_HEIGHT=400

pygame.init()
WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )
pygame.display.set_caption("Map Loader")

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

TILE_SIZE = 32
wall_image  = pygame.image.load('brick_32.png')
grass_image = pygame.image.load('grass_32.png')

level = [
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                    PPPPPPPPPPP           P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P    PPPPPPPP                              P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                          PPPPPPP         P",
    "P                 PPPPPP                   P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P         PPPPPPP                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                     PPPPPP               P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P   PPPPPPPPPPP                            P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                 PPPPPPPPPPP              P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "P                                          P",
    "PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPP",]


def drawMap( screen, level ):
    level_width = len(level[0])  # width for first row
    level_height = len(level)    # number of rows

    for y in range( level_height ):
        for x in range ( level_width ):
            if ( level[y][x] == 'P' ):
                screen.blit( wall_image, ( x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE) )
            elif ( level[y][x] == ' ' ):
                screen.blit( grass_image, (x*TILE_SIZE, y*TILE_SIZE) )

def drawGameWindow( screen ):
    global WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT
    drawMap( screen, level )
    pygame.display.update()
    pygame.display.flip()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()
done = False
while not done:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if ( event.type == pygame.QUIT ):
            done = True
        elif ( event.type == pygame.VIDEORESIZE ):
            WINDOW_WIDTH  = event.w
            WINDOW_HEIGHT = event.h
            WINDOW  = pygame.display.set_mode( ( WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT ), pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF|pygame.RESIZABLE )

    # Movement keys
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if ( keys[pygame.K_UP] ):
        print("up")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_DOWN] ):
        print("down")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_LEFT] ):
        print("left")
    elif ( keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] ):
        print("right")

    drawGameWindow( WINDOW )
    clock.tick_busy_loop( 60 )


pygame.quit()
```

Obviously in a real game, the map is much bigger than the screen.  So code needs to be written to draw only the correct section of the map onto the screen.  The example code above naively just draws from the top-left corner. If the list-map were quite complicated, it may be worthwhile to load all the tile-textures into a dictionary, and then just *paint-by-numbers*, e.g.: `textures['P']` -> `textures[ level[y][x] ]`

There are also python libraries which will handle all this sort of thing already.  One popular example is [TMX](https://github.com/renfredxh/tmx), but there are a few others.

*Offtopic, but relevant note*:

If you've ever seen a [Roguelike game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roguelike) (my personal favourite is [Angband](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angband_(video_game))), they use letters as "graphic" elements, e.g. the player is `@`, a Dragon is `d` or `D`, they never needed the use of *fancy* graphics, and made a great game with just the textual symbols.